# Elastic gem. Why are the classes being compared incorrectly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I use *elasticsearch-model* and *elasticsearch-rails* gems in my rails project.
After searching, bunch of records are paginated and *records* method being called.

```
records = search_results.page(count).records
```

and when I got first record from records, for example, entity of Product class, and compare with class it returns false, but entity class is Product, why?

```
#returns Product entity

records.first

records.first.is_a?(Product)     #=> false
records.first.class == Product   #=> false
records.first.class.name         #=> "Product"
```

I can compare with class.name == "Product", but why classes don't compare correctly?

**EDIT**: method **records** returns the collection of records from the database

Comment: Do you have multiple `Product` classes / modules? Try `records.first.is_a?(::Product)`

Comment: @Stefan Product model without a module or something else, I tried what you say, but without success.

Comment: Can you add the result of `records.first.class.ancestors`? `records.first.class.name` can mask a lot of things because `name` is just a method like any other.